# Filtering through an array based on its ID

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, vue-router

I need to loop through my filteredArray. Objects in specified array have multiple properties like description, time, id and so on.
I want to filter the array based on  ID so i want to get back object with the desired ID, so i will be able to use it and print out its description, time etc.

Here is my v-for:

```
 <h1
          class="content"
          v-for="(record, index) of filteredRecords"
          :key="index"
          :class="{ 'is-active': index === activeSpan }"
        >
          
          <strong>{{ record.description }}</strong>
        </h1>
```

this is how i am filtering my array:

```
filteredRecords() {
  return this.records.filter(record => {
    return record.id === this.id;
  });
}
```

How to return entire object from this function?

what i have right now:

```
records:[{
  description: "xy",
  time: 12,
  id: 5
}, {
  description: "xy",
  time: 12,
  id: 6

}, {
  description: "xy",
  time:12321,
  id:7
}]
```

what i want to get is for example everything with the id  7 so:

desired output:

```
filteredRecords:[{
  description: "xy",
  time: 12321,
  id: 7
}]
```

Comment: "I need the whole array from the filter" — the whole point of `.filter()` is to filter **out** some elements of the original array. If you don't want to do that, then it makes no sense to use `.filter()`.

Comment: You are not filtering if you need the whole array, they are opposite concepts. Please better explain what the 'filter' is supposed to do

Comment: i got you so what should i do instad,like mapping through?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Please provide an example of the data before and the data you need after

Comment: What you do is already what you want then. What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: no its not writing out anything in my <h1></h1>,

not writing out the description...

Comment: In short question is: How to show specific element not entire array. Filter doesn't work.

Comment: what is `this.id` and is this function a computed propertie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is simply that you are missing the () in the'v-for'.  So, instead of having this:

```
v-for="(record, index) of filteredRecords"
```

You should have this:

```
v-for="(record, index) of filteredRecords()"
```

Comment: I assumed it was a computed property and in that case the `()` is optional, but you may be right

Comment: its just not working .. i dont know why , where should i add my filteredRecords method? in methods or in computed?  but i dont think thats the problem

Comment: my bad i had a typo your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the filtering, it is in the vue section:

Instead of

```js
v-for="(record, index) of filteredRecords"
```

use

```js
v-for="(record, index) in filteredRecords"
```

Comment: They are not identical, one uses the `for..in` syntax, the other the `for..of` syntax

Comment: no its not working unfortunately.

Comment: @endoftheworld What is not working? Add a `debugger;` inside and open dev tools. Inside `filteredRecords`, assign the array returned by filter to a variable and check it's value by logging it. Check the value of `this.id`. Return a dummy array and check it it's displaying in the HTML. Inspect the HTML and check the rendered code. Please. Debug. Your. Code.